# The variable "approaches" or "goes away from" 0?

Tags: phrase-request

I have some candidates for the former case(x -> 0):

**The variable approaches zero.

The variable approximates to zero.

The variable are closing zero.

The variable becomes more and more equal to zero.**

I don't know which of those above are native expressions and if I can say:

**The variable goes away from zero.**

to convey the opposite meaning?

Comment: I'm not native English but I think that "are closing zero" is not gramtically correct nor idiomatic. And instead of "become more and more equal to zero", what about "the variable tends to zero"?

Comment: @RubioRic Seems great! Danke!

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about a value which is the limit of an expression or series then the usual word would be approaches or tends to. Behind this is the idea of a figurative motion to that limit. We do not have MathJax enabled here so it is hard to give mathematical expressions but since I see you are active on CrossValidated you may be familiar with series which approach a limiting value as *n* tends to infinity, like the one for *e*.

We use approximate when that idea of figurative motion is absent, so 22/7 approximates the value of pi.

Answer (score 0):

> The variable approaches zero.

This is correct.

> The variable approximates to zero.

This is grammatically correct, but actually means the variable is almost zero (for example 0.0001). It doesn't convey any movement of the variable.

> The variable are closing zero.

This is incorrect, but *"The variable closes towards zero"* is fine for casual conversation. For a situation where perfect grammar is important though, this is not recommended.

> The variable becomes more and more equal to zero.

I guess this is *kind of* okay. A lot of native speakers would definitely say this, but it's really incorrect because *equal* is binary. You can't really be a *little bit equal* (even though lots of people would still use it that way).

As for conveying the opposite meaning, there's actually not many options. *"The variable goes away from zero."* sounds a bit awkward, but I can't think of a better way to word it off the top of my head. Maybe someone else here can think of a good phrasing. Personally, I'd try a different approach altogether (*"The variable's value increases"*).

Comment: The terms "converges" and "diverges" can be used as The variable diverges from zero.

Comment: I think approximate as a transitive verb is alternative to converge here.

Comment: @lerner I looked it up in some dictionaries, and while some do list *approximate* as a synonym of *approach*, it's always one of the last (and thus least appropriate) synonyms. Personally, as a native British English speaker, I would never take *approximate* to mean *converge* and don't recommend using it as such. Especially so in this context, where *approximate*'s actual definition (to be close to) is potentially applicable.

Comment: @Omegastick Thanks for your reply. I saw this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence):  `In other words, it is the amount of information lost when Q is used to approximate P`.

Comment: @lerner Yes, this means the amount of information that is lost when you substitute Q for P because Q is close to P.